# vlookup to look for value in second column

Tags: vba, indexing, vlookup

I have the following 2 tables (Odds & Bets).

Table1

[image: Table1]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2]

I want to compare TransId from table 2 with TransId from table 1 and retrieve some values and paste the same in Price column in table 2. 
I have a VLOOKUP function in my VBA code, to do this job. However it iterates through first column (oddsId) and therefore fetches wrong price (hope this is expected as Vlookup always look for left most column, if i am not wrong).

But i want to compare both TransId to get the price info.

Price column uses the formula:

```
=getprice(BetsTable[[#This Row],[TransId]],BetsTable[[#This Row],[Option]])
```

Following is the code sample for GetPrice:

```
Function GetPrice(transId, opt)
Dim bettype As String

opt = UCase(opt)

bettype = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(transId, Range("OddsTable5"), 3, False)

If (bettype = "FT.HDP" Or bettype = "HT.HDP") Then
    If (opt = "H") Then
        GetPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(transId, Range("OddsTable5"), 14, False)
    ElseIf (opt = "A") Then
        GetPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(transId, Range("OddsTable5"), 15, False)
    Else
        GetPrice = "Error"
    End If
```

I want to handle this situation in my VBA code (getPrice function). Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a range for VLookup to use by removing the first column.

```
dim odds_range as range
with Range("OddsTable5")
  set odds_range = Range( .Cells(1,2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) )
end with

...

GetPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(transId, odds_range, 14, False)
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it results the same error. I have edited my post to include the image of sheet for your reference.   Does the .Cell(1,2) point to Column 2 ?

Comment: Yes it does. It won't work if that yellow bar on top is a merged cell that is also included in the range. `OddsTable5` must only include the table, with or without headers.